# xcode 8 swift 3 slow down function's "firing" time

Tags: timer, swift3, xcode8

I'm having trouble creating a gun that shoots at variable speeds (i.e. revolver vs machine gun). Right now I have this code for the actual firing of the bullet:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


func spawnBullets(_ location: CGPoint){
    let Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")
    Bullet.zPosition = -1
    Bullet.position = CGPoint(x: ship.position.x,y: ship.position.y)
    Bullet.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

    Bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 15)
    Bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet
    Bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    Bullet.name = "Bullet"
    Bullet.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    Bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.addChild(Bullet)

    var dx = CGFloat(location.x - base2.position.x)
    var dy = CGFloat(location.y - base2.position.y)

    let magnitude = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

    dx /= magnitude
    dy /= magnitude

    let vector = CGVector(dx: 30.0 * dx, dy: 30.0 * dy)
    Bullet.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
```

and then I have this in a later section

```
         override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch in (touches ){
let location = touch.location(in: self)
         if ball3.frame.contains(location) && base2.frame.contains(location) == false{
                        spawnBullets(location)}
```

I've tried using a timer function yet it seems just to make things worse. Right now the bullets are firing at a rate of 60 per seconds (or just the same rate as the fps). Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to add a cool down to reduce your bullet spawn rate. Add a `cooldown` property to your scene:

`var cooldown = 0`

When `spawnBullets` is called you can set the cooldown delay you want between shots based on the gun e.g. `cooldown = 30 // Basing this on a constant 60fps the bullet will have a cooldown of 0.5 seconds`

You will need to add a check for the `cooldown`, in `touchesMoved` you could add `&& cooldown == 0` to your conditional.

In your `update` method, decrement the `cooldown`:

```
if cooldown > 0 { cooldown -= 1 }
```